# Retrive data from php file in angularjs 2

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, angular2-routing

> In angularjs 2 How to post data and get response from php page ?
>               using http post
>               Ex: my requirment is to post data  from auth.js file to session.php to store session and get that session value ?

```
return this._http.get('../session.php' + token)
     .map((res: Response) => {
      console.log(res.json());
      return res;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the HTTP method from 'get' to 'post' and it's gonna work.

```
 return this._http.post('../session.php' + token, body)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```